# How to wrap/intercept an Angular scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make use of an Angular multiselect directive ([isteven/angular-multi-select](https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select) to be specific) as a multi-select interface component. The problem with it is that the data it returns is an array of the selected objects in full, whereas we'd rather work with a reduced version of the object such as an array of IDs. Since this component is already being wrapped by our own directive for abstraction, I'd like to find some way to intercept the child scope value as it's being modified and then return that reduced value through the ngModel scope property on my wrapper directive.

**Directive Definition**

```
angular.module('cw-ui').directive('cwSelect', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            options: '=',
            maxLabels: '@?',
            selectionMode: '@?',
            onClose: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'UI/Directives/select',
        compile: function(element, attributes) {
            if(attributes.maxLabels === undefined) {
                attributes.maxLabels = 3;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**Wrapping Directive Template**

```
<isteven-multi-select input-model="options" output-model="ngModel" button-label="icon name" item-label="icon name maker" tick-property="ticked" group-property="msGroup" max-labels="{{::maxLabels}}" selection-mode="{{selectionMode}}" on-close="onClose()"></isteven-multi-select>
```

Comment: if the directive you posted is for the html element you posted should then not the directive called istevenMultiSelect or the element have a attr cw-select ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have been clearer that I was posting the template for the wrapping directive. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't entirely follow but one not-so-elegant way to do this is put a watch on the model value modified by the isteven directive and then package that data however you want into some other model object for use by your own directive.

Comment: Yeah I'd thought to do that earlier...like you say, not a super-elegant way to solve the problem, but it would let me transform the data albeit in an expensive way.

Comment: how does your directive get access to the data? You can always _.map(outputArray, function(item) { return item.id }